# ¿Cómo puedo recuperar el id de la tabla A y llevarlo a la tabla B para dar de alta un registro?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lo que quiero hacer es que en un mismo formulario dar de alta un cliente(tabla A) y sus compras(tabla B).

*Primero insertar el nombre del cliente, en un texbox.

*Luego agregar o ingresar sus compras.

*Despues de que los campos de ambas tablas esten llenadas realizar el submit para que al mismo tiempo las tablas sean afectadas, pero recuperando el id del cliente que se dio de alta para poder relacionarla con sus compras.

Comment: Usando [la cláusula OUTPUT](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql).

Comment: Que tal Isa, bienvenid@... podremos ayudarte si nos muestras lo que tienes hecho... este tipo de preguntas son mal vistas por la comunidad. Simplemente el sitio no esta hecho para resolver tareas... Por favor ve a [ask]  para poder mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta, y de paso podes hacer el [tour] para saber como funcionamos... mucha suerte

Comment: Si la columna ClienteID es autoincremental puedes hacer algo del estilo
insert into Clientes (Nombre) values (@nombre);Select @@IDENTITY

Comment: Ya recuperé el id del cliente de esa forma, pero ahora como lo llevo a la otra tabla?

Comment: La solución óptima es el comentario de Luis Cazares, si vas por el lado de leer directamente el `IDENTITY` te sugiero en todo caso:  [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es un esquema de un procedimiento almacenado que realizaría la tarea que quieres.

```
create procedure PedidoNuevoCliente
@NombreCliente varchar(50),
, @ProductoID int
, @Cantidad int
as
declare @NuevoClienteID int;

insert into Clientes (Nombre) values (@NombreCliente);Select @NuevoClienteID  = 
@@IDENTITY;

insert into Pedidos (ClienteID, ProductoID, Cantidad)
select @NuevoClienteID, @ProductoID, @Cantidad;
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió mucho!!

Comment: Te recomiendo usar SCOPE_IDENTITY() en lugar de @@IDENTITY. Si tu tabla Clientes tiene un trigger que inserta en otra tabla, @@IDENTITY no devuelve el id de Clientes, sino el del registro insertado en la segunda tabla.

Answer (score 0):

por ende tiene que realizar un insert en la tabla A y luego recuperar su id
para insertarlo en la tabla B

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO A(name, email) VALUES(?,?)");

 $tmt->execute( array('user', 'user@example.com'));

 print $dbh->lastInsertId()

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO B(name, email) VALUES(?,?)");

 $tmt->execute( array('user', 'user@example.com'));
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero te sugerimos revisar [answer], edita tu respuesta, saludos.